# How to Create a user Dedicated innoDb Buffer pool or create a Query Dedicated innodb buffer pool

Tags: mysql, innodb, buffer-pool

we are using 16 GB RAM and We have Allotted 4Gb space to Mysql InnoDB Buffer Pool IS there any way we can create multiple Buffer pool in INNoDB or Can we create a User Named Buffer Pool or Per Query Buffer Pool i.e. Set explain Path For permanent.

1. How can we make sure that some queries remain in our buffer pool Permanently?
2. if a user fetch same type of data from mysqldb can a part of buffer pool be dedicated to that specific user?

Comment: This question is about configuring mysql, not about programming, therefore it is off topic here on SO. The DBA sister site of SO deals with such questions. Btw, the first one is definitely not possible, innodb buffer pool is not a cache. Use an in-memory cache software for this purpose.

Comment: generally you can't do any of these things. The buffer pool is a global LRU cache. Which MySQL version are you after a solution for? You can keep pages in the pool with regular use. Do you have a specific case where the performance of an uncommon query is of the highest importance? What problem are you solving?

Comment: @Shadow Thanks for your response IS there any way we can create multiple Buffer pool in INNoDB or Can we create a User Named Buffer Pool or user dedicated bufferpool

Comment: @danblack  Thanks for your response IS there any way we can create multiple Buffer pool in INNoDB  i.e. create a User dedicated Buffer Pool or Query dedicated bufferpool. something Like Hybrid bufferpool?

Comment: @Shadow let me elaborte what i meant from query dedicated BufferPool say for example when we run a query first time it takes 10.00 sec to Execute and when we run the same query again it takes 0.600ms to execute is there any possibility that this query execution time remain stable to 0.600ms or less everytime we execute this query. is it possible for a query to remain in a buffer pool maximum time. do we have to use another Storage engine ??

Comment: "you can't do any of these things". Show the query, its query plan (EXPLAIN {query}) and the actual problem.

Comment: @adilkhan you either follow danblack's guidance and edit your question to fit with SO. As a reminder: SO is a programming Q/A site. Or you need to ask you question on the DBA sister site of SO.

Comment: This is a typical example of the [X-Y problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). You have some performance goal in mind and you believe that a user- or query-dedicated bufferpool (both of which don't exist, by the way) is the solution. Instead, you should state your goal and let people offer realistic solutions. To that end, please consider reading [this advice](https://dba.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3034/asking-query-performance-questions).

Comment: It may be possible to speed up the query.  Let's see it.

Answer (score 2):

No, for the record there is no feature in MySQL or InnoDB to create dedicated buffer pools for particular queries.

You may not have a correct understanding of what the InnoDB buffer pool contains. It does not contain query results, it contains pages of data and indexes, exactly as they are stored on disk. The same page in the buffer pool may serve multiple different queries.

There is no way to ensure certain pages stay in the buffer pool. They are managed by an LRU algorithm (least recently used). Over time, data pages that are queried more frequently tend to remain in the buffer pool. InnoDB also has some special handling so pages aren't evicted too easily by a single query. You can read more about the details here: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/innodb-buffer-pool.html

MySQL used to have something called the [query cache](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/query-cache.html), which is an in-memory cache of results for specific queries. But it was also an LRU-type cache. You could not dedicate a query cache to a specific query. Multiple queries shared the query cache, and they could be evicted.

Besides that, the query cache was deprecated in MySQL 5.7 and removed from MySQL 8.0. The problem with any such automatic cache is that it ends up being expensive to keep the cache in sync with data. Every time data in a given table changed, the cached query results that used that table were purged. On a table that updated frequently, this became a bottleneck for performance. The other problem with the query cache is that if it's enabled, it's enabled for all queries and all tables by default, even those that don't need it.

A better solution for your requirements is to implement a query cache in your application. Then you can decide which queries need to be cached, you can decide how often you want to sync these cached results with the data in the database, you can decide what format to use in the cache.

Comment: Remember when MyISAM had dedicated key caches ??? ( from the olden days of MySQL Archeology )

Comment: @RolandoMySQLDBA, yep, but that's only for MyISAM tables, which I haven't used in years. And it  isn't a per-query cache anyway; it's a per-index cache.

Comment: @BillKarwin Thanks a lot for your suggestion kindly provide roadmap for implementing query cachae in my application

Comment: The general idea is to store the query result in a cache after the first time you run the SQL query. Then on subsequent requests for the same query, use the cached result instead of running the SQL query again. There are whole books about this subject. Start with a good tutorial. There are many, but here's an example: https://medium.com/fintechexplained/advanced-python-how-to-implement-caching-in-python-application-9d0a4136b845